# Restsharp deserialize failed when sending Dictionary<int,string> parameter to RestAPI

Tags: .net, rest, json.net, restsharp, json-deserialization

I've created a restsharp api:

```
object Ping(Dictionary<int, string> item);
```

This api returns constant string.
When calling it there is a BadRequest http status with the following message:

```
Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.Int32,System.String]'
```

because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. `{"name":"value"}`) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

It seems that the RestSharp doesn't know how to deserialize the dictionary. I tried to serialize it with Json.NET, send to the server by JSON and deserialize on the server side and it does work.

I've read that on previous RestSharp's versions it was possible to replace the serializer class, is it possible to do it on 105.2.3.0? How?
Do you have another idea to solve this problem for me?

Comment: Could you paste your json?

Answer (score 0):

You can try deserialize response to dictionary by using:

```
RestSharp.Deserializers.JsonDeserializer deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();

var jsonDataDictionary = deserializer.Deserialize<Dictionary<int, string>>(response); 

var valueFromDictionary =  jsonDataDictionary[0]; //to get element value
```